# How can i get the Metadata of my Tables before they annotated to my Configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to add my Entity's to my SessionFactory but i don't know the classes when i start the programm.

After i connect with Hibernate to the Database i want get the Metadata from the Database and use them for example to find the classes that i want to add.

This is the way how i get the Metadata but it only works if add the classes in the hibernate.cfg.xml or add them static in my HibernateUtil before i create the Sessionfactory.

```
        Map metaa = qCon.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();

        Set set = metaa.entrySet();

        Iterator it = set.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext())
        {
          Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) it.next();
              // Do something with the values...
        }
```

Now i want to add the classes at runtime with addAnnotatedClass().

Is there any way to get the Metadata from the tables in the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain [JDBC connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29) to get database metadata. But that will give you table names, not entity names. If you can calculate entity class name from a table name, then you can use `Class.forName(entityClassName)`.

Comment: That a way. I'll try it. Thanks